# ATmega2560 assembly pin read and compare logic problem

Tags: atmega, atmel, assembly, atmel-studio

I apologize if my question was vague.

Program: Atmel Studio 6

I am trying to make a program that enters an loop which it will only break out of when a pin goes low.

```
;Set PA0 high before entering loop checking for low
CBI DDRA,DDA0       ;PA0 to input
SBI PINA0,0         ;PA0 pull-up enable
;PA0 is now input & high

chklow: inc r16     ; Increase r16
in r18,PORTA0       ; Copies PINA0 to r18
cpi r18,0           ; Compares r18 to 0
brne chklow         ; Branch if PA0 is not low
nop             ; Loop exit (do nothing)
```

What happens is that when I set PINA0, PORTA0 goes high. I guess this is good, it's like I pressed a button attached to PINA0.

Now I enter the loop, and I have my I/O view box up, so I see that PORTA0 is set. This is the rightmost box in PORTA.

But "in r18,PORTA" doesn't make r18 become '1'... it remains 0.

And so the Z-bit is set to 1 because the compare succeeded, and the branch doesn't occur.

What's wrong? I want the loop to continue indefinitely until I make PORTA0 low.

EDIT: I changed it now, using your advice:

```
CBI DDRA,DDA0           ;PA0 to input
SBI PORTA0,0            ;PA0 pull-up enable


chklow:
in r18,PORTA        ; Copies PINA0 to r18
cpi r18,0x00        ; Compares r18 to 0
brne chklow         ; Branch if PA0 is not low
nop             ; Loop exit (do nothing)
```

So what I changed was I copied the entire PORTA byte, instead of trying to copy the PORTA0 bit, which isn't possible (at least using my method), and now it works. Thanks ;)

Also, I know this is a dirty solution, because it fails if ANY bit in Pin A is set, but I can refine that later, this is a working prototype :D

Comment: Why do your comments not match your code?

Comment: I thought they did. Can you point to what comment does not match?

Comment: `in r18,PORTA0       ; Copies PINA0 to r18`

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Ah ok. Well you see I figured if a Port was '1', and the pin is for reading the value of the Port, then reading the Pin is equivalent with reading the Port. Am I wrong in this understanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple things that make me frown:

```
SBI PINA0,0         ;PA0 pull-up enable
```

According to the datasheet:

> Three I/O memory address locations are allocated for each port, one each for the Data Register – PORTx, Data Direction Register – DDRx, and the Port Input Pins – PINx. The Port Input Pins I/O location is read only, while the Data Register and the Data Direction Register are read/write. However, *writing a logic one to a bit in the PINx Register, will result in a toggle in the corresponding bit in the Data Register.* In addition, the Pull-up Disable – PUD bit in MCUCR disables the pull-up function for all pins in all ports when set.

To enable the pull-up you should write to `PORTA` not to `PINA0`. Also notice the difference `PINA0` and `PINA` in your code. You cannot read a single bit from an IO port, you must read the whole byte. Then you can check one or more bits in the byte read using `AND`, `SBRC` or `SBRS`.

```
nop             ; Loop exit (do nothing)
```

Don't use `nop` to "do nothing", because the microcontroller will go forward to the next instruction in flash which can be *anything*, including an instruction from a previous program that was in flash if it wasn't overwritten. Anything can happen from there.

Comment: While writing to `PINx` like this may work by accident (since writing to `PINx` inverts the bits in `PORTx`), I agree that you should not do it this way.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Added a related quote from the datasheet.

Comment: Yes, I did read the datasheet and sent 1 to pin because as it says, it toggles the port. But why doesn't "in r18,PORTA0" cause the value from PORTA0, which is 1, to go to r18..?

Comment: @jippie, I have now made it to write to PORTA instead. Does the same, but as you say, cleaner. OK. How can I now get the value of PORTA0 bit to r18, so I can then compare it to '0'?

Comment: @DrOnline How do you know it doesn't work? Your code doesn't do anything useful after the `brne`

Comment: @jippie Well I can see that the leftmost bit in PORTA is set, that is PORTA0. So PORTA0=1, as I understand it. Then i get to the line "in r18,PORTA0", and r18 remains '0'.... Why does it not become '1'?

Comment: @jippie To be clear about what I want: I want to set PORTA0 high. Then enter a loop which copies the value from PORTA0 to r16, then compares that value to '0', and doesn't leave the loop until PORTA0 has been set to '0'.

Comment: You have to read the whole byte from `PORTA`, then test bit0, for example with `AND R18,0x01`.  You cannot read a single bit from a port directly.

Comment: An alternative for testing with `AND` are the `SBRC` and `SBRS` instructions.

Comment: @jippie Thank you. I didn't know this I had to read the whole byte. Thanks a lot. I can't upvote yet because I have no rep, or I would ;)

Comment: Oh, and the nop, well I intend to add more program below that, so it was there in wait for me to expand things :D